# Prevent setup-config.php page from appearing when host blocks database

Tags: security, customization

My hosting service has following limitation.

- The maximum number of database queries per user is 75,000/hr.

My site rarely exceeds that limitation, so I don't want go for a new hosting.

But, when that limit is exceeded, my site will display the following screenshot:

**This allow user to overwrite my files. Is there way to stop it?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not completely clear how your provider is handling the the resource overage, but the situation described in the question can be reproduced by setting up `wp-config.php` to connect to an empty database. From the looks of it, someone would be able to proceed with the WordPress installation.

This solution will prevent WordPress from being reinstalled.

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file to prevent access to the WordPress installation scripts:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent wp-admin/install(-helper)?\.php /site-unavailable.html
```

Create the file `site-unavailable.html` in the site's root directory and add message stating that the site is currently unavailable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site temporarily unavailable</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { font-size: 16px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <p>Our site is experiencing a high volume of traffic and will return soon.</p>
    </article>
</body>
```

This will redirect any attempts to load the install files `wp-admin/install.php` and `wp-admin/install-helper.php` to `http://domain.com/site-unavailable.html`.